# Velocity of displaced object

Tags: buoyancy

If I were to submerge an object in a large body of water and it is buoyed upwards long enough for it to almost reach terminal velocity, what would be the object's maximum velocity once it reaches the surface?

For example, if you hold a rubber ball several inches under water in a pool and then let go, it will typically pop up out of the water several inches.  If you then hold the same rubber ball several feet under water in the same pool and then let go, it will typically pop up out of the water much higher than before.  How do you calculate the velocity the rubber ball has gained by the buoyant force in a denser medium such as water to understand how high it will potentially travel upwards when it transitions to a less dense medium such as air?

[Terminal Velocity of buoyant object](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/122232/terminal-velocity-of-buoyant-object) seems to come the closest to answering this question.

Comment: You can easily use the work energy theorem to calculate the final speed.

Comment: If the linked question helps, how can you apply it to your problem?  You must show some effort.